# OpenGeo Suite PostGIS Data Location

Tags: postgis, boundless-suite

I have OpenGeo Suite installed on a server. I want to have the PostGIS data stored on a different drive (D) on the server instead of on the C drive under my username. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a new tablespace.  A tablespace is a physical location Postgres saves your data to.  Here's the Postgres manual entry on creating new tablespaces:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtablespace.html